# Change one string to keyword highlight with PHP

Tags: php

I Have this text :

```
test1
test1
test1
test1
test1
test1
```

And i need to have this with pHP :

```
test1,test1,test1,test1,test1,test1
```

I want a simple php code to do that with string .

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all newlines with `,`. There might also be a carriage return there.

```
str_replace("\n", ",", $input);
// or
str_replace("\r\n", ",", $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function highlight($searchtext, $text) {
    return preg_replace('#' . $searchtext . '#is', '<span style="background-color:green">$0</span>', $text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: `$string = trim(str_replace("\n", ',' $string), ',');`

You could also use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n`.

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is problematic on input files because you don't know _what_ made the file. It might be that your server is Linux but all your users run Windows. Also, a regexp is overkill here, there is no dynamic input.